# How to show content below bottom tab bar in React-Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have to do a very custom design for the bottom navigation bar. I use ImageBackground for my screen and I need the navigation bar to draw over it, not below it.

I guess the problem is the `SafeAreaView` that is being used behind the scenes. How do I remove that?

Edit: I am working on Android and I just found that SafeAreaView only works on iOS. so maybe I need a different way to implement my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the tab bar absolutely and set a transparent background color:

```js
tabBarOptions: {
  style: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent'
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify that tabBarOptions is set on the Tab.Navigatior